# application would like to Access the Microphone ios alert

Tags: ios, uialertview, microphone

Is there any way to customise the alert message of apple's default "xyzapplication would like to Access the Microphone screen". I'm using SIAlertview in my application which works good for all other screens but apple's default alert for permission to access photos or microphone is of the system's alertview.

Comment: no you cant customize

Comment: You can try to change the appearance from the appdelegate, I haven't tried it, but just a thought.

Comment: @maddy:I wanted to change the default uialertview of the alert  message to custom alertview which I used all through the app.Is there any means to change the default uialertview to the custom alertview for the permission alerts

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question well enough. No, there is no way to tell iOS to use a different class for system alerts. You can only customize the message.